# way to get data without metadata(ID3) from mp3

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, mp3, id3

Is there any way to get data removed metadata(for example, ID3) from mp3 file with Objective-C, C++, or C?

there are similar function in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.id3-remove-tag.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Use a library (For ID3, there are library implementations listed on [ID3.org](http://id3.org/Implementations)).

If for some reason you cannot use a library, removing a single ID3 tag from a file is quite a trivial process (search for the characters 'ID3' and then look at the header to get the tag size in bytes ([details of the header found here](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure)). The tag will be contiguous so you can just remove it using a file descriptor.